# Button.isEnabled() returns true even though the button is disabled by default

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, isenabled

While testing I got a road block where I have a button in a WebPage which is disabled by default. I am using Selenium WebDriver to test if the button is disabled by default the boolean is always returning true.

```
Boolean buttonStatus = (button XPath).isEnabled
```

It will be great if someone can help me

[image: Test Button is disabled by default]

HTML Information:

```
<div class="commandbutton commandbutton--theme-disabled commandbutton--recommended">
<button class="commandbutton-button commandbutton-button--disabled" type="button" tabindex="-1">
```

Comment: Please copy/paste your HTML source as text, not an image.

Comment: I have added the HTML source text to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [isEnabled docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.html#isEnabled--)

> This will generally return true for everything but disabled input
>   elements.

But it will work on buttons as well. However, `isEnabled()` checks for the `disabled` attribute. If the button is disabled by JavaScript or any other means `isEnabled()` won't detect it.

My guess is the button has other classes when it is enabled or disabled. For example, when enabled it probably won't have `commandbutton-button--disabled` class. You can check for it

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("button XPath"));
String classes = button.getAttribute("class");
boolean isDisabled = classes.contains("commandbutton-button--disabled");
```

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But my elements on the page were very strange. Some of them selenium could click although they were not clickable, some of them selenium couldn't click, but could send keys to them. After a few hours of thinking, I have wrote universal method, that checks if elements is enabled or not.

After talking with programmer, I have known, that they use on this page some special Select, and it looks like Div with Input in it. And he says, that I can check it disabling by checking attribute Class of Div. If there is 'select2-container-disabled' then this Input is disabled.

And I change my method. Now it looks like that:

```
 public boolean isNotClickable(WebElement... elements) {
    List<WebElement> elementsChecked = new ArrayList<>();
    List<WebElement> elementsToCheckByClass = new ArrayList<>();
    List<WebElement> elementsToCheckByClick = new ArrayList<>();
    List<WebElement> elementsToCheckBySendKeys = new ArrayList<>();

    for (WebElement checkedElement : elements) {
        log.info("Checking, that element [" + getLocator(checkedElement) + "] is not clickable by isEnabled()");
        if (checkedElement.isEnabled()) {
            elementsToCheckByClass.add(checkedElement);
        } else {
            elementsChecked.add(checkedElement);
        }
    }
    if (!elementsToCheckByClass.isEmpty()) {
        for (WebElement checkedByClassElement : elementsToCheckByClass) {
            log.info("Checking, that element [" + getLocator(checkedByClassElement) + "] is not clickable by class");
            String classOfElement = checkedByClassElement.getAttribute("class");
            List<String> classes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(classOfElement.split(" ")));
            if (!classes.contains("select2-container-disabled")) {
                elementsToCheckByClick.add(checkedByClassElement);
            } else {
                elementsChecked.add(checkedByClassElement);
            }
        }
    }
    if (!elementsToCheckByClick.isEmpty()) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driverUtils.getDriver(), 1);
        for (WebElement checkedByClickElement : elementsToCheckByClick) {
            log.info("Checking, that element [" + getLocator(checkedByClickElement) + "] is not clickable by clicking it");
            try {
                wait.until(elementToBeClickable(checkedByClickElement));
                elementsToCheckBySendKeys.add(checkedByClickElement);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                elementsChecked.add(checkedByClickElement);
            }
        }
    }
    if (!elementsToCheckBySendKeys.isEmpty()) {
        for (WebElement checkedBySendKeysElement : elementsToCheckBySendKeys) {
            log.info("Checking, that element [" + getLocator(checkedBySendKeysElement) + "] is not clickable by sending keys");
            try {
                checkedBySendKeysElement.sendKeys("checking");
                return false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                elementsChecked.add(checkedBySendKeysElement);
            }
        }
    }
    return elementsChecked.size() == elements.length;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

isEnabled can only tell you the button works fine, you need to check the class attribute to check is the button is enabled.

Comment: *isEnabled can only tell you the button works fine* what are you talking about?